# Best practices to reduce size for protobuf messages?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am sending positional/rotational data (vector3,quaternions) using protobuf-net messages from a client in c# to a server in c++.

At the start I tried a hierarchical approach in the form of

```
Message Vector3
{ 
int32 x = 1;
int32 y = 2;
int32 z = 3;
}

Message Transform
{
Vector3 trackedPos1 = 1;
Vector3 trackedPos2 = 2;
Vector3 trackedPos3 = 3;
}
```

and the hierarchy grows larger and larger and with it the overhead from the protobuff messages. I can flatten the messages into a single one but it am not sure how managable it will become.

So anyone got any idea how to tackle this with low overhead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be worth thinking whether you can re-structure the tree to make use of "packed arrays" - for example, if you are sending 200 `Transform` (so: 600 `Vector3` and 1800 `int32`), via

```
repeated Transform data = 1;
```

you could simplify a *lot* by just sending a single:

```
repeated int32 data = 1 [packed = true];
```

that is 1800-long. In protobuf-net terms this can be handled as:

```
[ProtoMember(1, IsPacked = true)]
public int[] Data {get;set;}
```

This avoids:

- 1800 field headers for the integers
- 200 field headers for the `Transform` instances
- 200 length-prefixes for the `Transform` instances
- 600 field headers for the `Vector3` instances
- 600 length-prefixes for the `Vector3` instances

instead just using a single field header and a single length-prefix

It will, however, require different processing. You would have to manually treat each chunk of 9 successive values as a Transform.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc! I 've been reading gaffer on games and he does something like this as well.

In order to avoid to resend all nonchanging data  a bit or bool array  or a flag of enums will suffice to mark what I ll be sending?

Comment: @T.Zak ah, that's an entirely separate thing - and one that wouldn't play nicely with the idea I've proposed above; that's something that needs designing based on your specific scenario. protobuf-net supports full conditional serialization (via the `ShouldSerialize*()` pattern) - but that isn't a "yes/no" question so I can't give a simple answer